# Nginx - Wordpress Upload only images rule

Tags: uploads

Is there a rule I can add to `nginx config` which will allow users to be able to upload only images with a ".jpg" extension ?

I am aware that a hacker could potentially execute php code within an image but at least this is a security measure which is nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already denies trying to upload PHP file, then there is no security hole at this place. read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files